# How to listen to an array of channels with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, nodes

I am trying to listen on multiple channels dynamically with socket.io.

For example instead of

```
socket.on('room1',(room1Obj)=>{...})
socket.on('room2',(room2Obj)=>{...})
...
socket.on('roomN',(roomNObj)=>{...})
```

would it be possible to have the room names in an array and if a message is emitted and you happened to be in one of the rooms within the array than you could take actions.

```
//This is not the syntax but something like this
socket.on([arrayOfMyRooms],(arrayOfMyRooms Obj)=>{...})
```

Alternatively, I could have the server broadcast the room name and on the client side, those who have the room in the array could take action.

However performance wise, I am worried that this method will not scale for even a few thousands of users.

Please let me know if there is a solution of a better design approach. Thank you as always.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a group and join all users to that group and broadcast the message to a particular group.

for join user

```
socket.join(`GROUP_NAME`);
```

for broadcast in group

```
io.sockets.in(`GROUP_NAME`).emit(`EVENT_NAME`, data);
```

Comment: Every client will get the 'Event', and filtering who should take action on the client side is not a problem. I am expecting lots of users to emit and receive this 'Event' so performance wise is this a good method and is this the only way?

Comment: I think this is best approach or wait for other solutions